# How to display the title of a data column in code.org app lab?

Tags: app-lab

Does anyone know how to do this? I have tried everything I could think of in terms of how it could be stored as a variable, but I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

The title of a column is shown as its key name. For example, this:
| id | value |
| -- | ----- |
| 1| 6       |
is shown as this:

```js
{
  id: 1,
  value: 6
}
```

The column name in this case is value. All you have to do is just put "value" (or whatever column name you're using) next to where you're showing the cell content.